# Regex pattern to capture numbers only, on a single line, but exclude date pattern

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation

Here is my current regex:

```
\b\d(?:[^\n\d]*\d){14}(?!\d)
```

Explanation:

- `\b`: Matches a word boundary so that first match digit is matched in a separate word
- `[^\n\d]*`: Matches 0 or more of any char that is not a digit and not a line break
- `(?:[^\n\d]*\d){14}`: Matches 14 digits optionally interspersed by 0 or more non-digits, non-line breaks

The problem with this pattern is that it matches various date pattern that should be excluded as shown in this [RegEx Demo](https://regexr.com/6vdhn).  You can see problem matches here identified in red:

[image]

I need to modify the current regex so that it will **not match** if it includes a date pattern.  Here is the [regex](https://regexr.com/6vdet) that I came up with to identify the various combinations of date patterns:

```
(?:[0-9]{1,4}[\-\/\\\.][0-9]{1,2}[\-\/\\\.][0-9]{1,4}){1}
```

This seems to match the required date patterns as shown here:

[image]

Now, if I could just figure out how to exclude the **second** pattern date matches from the **first** pattern of 15-digit matches. That is what I am trying to accomplish.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```bash
\b\d(?!(?:\d{0,3}([-\/\\.])\d{1,2}\1\d{1,4})\b(?!\S))(?:[^\n\d]*\d){14}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6VORZL/3)

Here `(?!(?:\d{0,3}([-\/\\\.])\d{1,2}\1\d{1,4})\b(?!\S))` is a negative lookahead pattern to avoid including dates in your matches.